# C++/CLI LoadLibrary Failing on Converting System::String to LPCWSTR and const char *

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Trying to pass in a user supplied string which has a path to the jvm.dll but it doesn't load the library unless I hard code with the following:

```
#define RUNTIME_DLL _T("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\Server\\jvm.dll")
```

It compiles but fails if I try this:

```
HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibrary((const char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(string).ToPointer());
```

The "string" var has the exact copy and pasted path that _T() has but still fails. Not an expert in C/C++ so I'm not sure what _T() gets it to work.

**Update:**

Tried this:

```
// System::String always stored as Unicode, get a Unicode pointer with no conversion necessary
        pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(string);
        // Always use the Unicode version of LoadLibrary
        HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);
```

And still it won't load the jvm.dll file.  It will only load it if I do this:

```
#define RUNTIME_DLL _T("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\Server\\jvm.dll")

        // System::String always stored as Unicode, get a Unicode pointer with no conversion necessary
        pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(RUNTIME_DLL);
        // Always use the Unicode version of LoadLibrary
        HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);
```

**Tried this as well:**

```
        // System::String always stored as Unicode
        marshal_context^ ctx = gcnew marshal_context();
        pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(jvmDllPath);           
        //const wchar_t * lib_name = ctx->marshal_as<const wchar_t*, System::String^>(jvmDllPath);
        printf("JVM Path: %s", lib_name);
        // Always use the Unicode version of LoadLibrary
        handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);            

        if( handle == 0) {
            printf("Failed to load jvm dll \n");
            //printf(ErrorExit((LPTSTR)(const char*)"Initialize"));
                            // this is the part that will work
            System::String^ string = gcnew System::String("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\Server\\jvm.dll");
            pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(string);
            handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);
        }
        delete ctx;  // do this for now to not create memory leaks
```

The C++/CLI method signature is:

```
void Initialize(String^ jvmDllPath)
```

The body is basically the code above

The C# code that calls into this with a string parameter is this:

```
obj.Initialize("c:\\program files\\java\\jdk7\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
```

Providing answer here from Ben's suggestion so people/newbs and temporary c/c++/cli coders can find a quick answer to avoid what I went through:

```
    const char * CliToNativeString(String^ cliString){
        const char * converted;
        converted = (gcnew marshal_context())->marshal_as<const char *>( cliString );           
        return converted;
    }

    String^ NativeToCliString(const char * nString){
        String^ converted = gcnew String("");
        if(nString != NULL)
            converted = (gcnew marshal_context())->marshal_as<String^>(nString); 
        return converted;
    }
```

Comment: I've also replaced the (const char *) cast with (LPCWSTR) and it compiles but still fails.... very odd.

Comment: Yes, casting will force your code to compile. That doesn't make it correct, or even require that it make any sense. If you write code that doesn't work, start by eliminating *all* of the casts and following the error diagnostics emitted by your compiler.

Comment: I'm aware but since working with C++/CLI casting is required so that ain't it. Thanks though.

Comment: No, there's no rule that casting is required for C++/CLI. The only thing casting is "required" for is masking bugs.

Comment: I have to cast as a variable of type String^ cannot be passed to LoadLibrary() unless I am missing something. Basically this is managed wrapper that is called/used/invoked by a C# program which passes in a type System::String to the C++/CLI wrapper. I must then cast this to a C style string for LoadLibrary() to work.  If I'm mistaken I would appreciate any pointers (no pun intended).

Comment: That's precisely my point. A cast just makes the compiler shut up, it doesn't actually perform the conversion that you need. The `System::String` managed type is *not* the same thing as the unmanaged C-style string, which is what the `LoadLibrary()` function is expecting. `LoadLibrary()` is a native Win32 API function that has absolutely no knowledge of .NET stuff like the `System::String` class. You have to do more than perform a cast; you have to actually *convert*. Ben's answer has what you need, and so does [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5.aspx).

Comment: A cast is just a way of telling the compiler, "I know what I'm doing, trust me". *Sometimes* that's what you want, but *very rarely*. And when it *is* what you want, you need to make sure that you document that very carefully. Lots of programmers hide mistakes by throwing in casts instead of understanding *why* the compiler is throwing that error and trying to use the diagnostics it provides to fix the problem. Any time I see a cast who use isn't carefully documented with a comment, I immediately consider it suspect.

Comment: @Cody: That series of examples on MSDN is terrible.  Point people to [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) and [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx) instead.

Comment: cool, thanks ... forgot that casts in C++ don't quite work like C#. Ok, will try the two methods in Ben's post. THanks guys. Got a deadline to meet! :/

Comment: The C# code uses "jdk7\jre", but the C++/CLI test constant has "jre7"

Comment: BTW that's not how `marshal_context` is meant to be used.  Oh darn, you got it from the example I referenced.  Stack semantics FTW, they're C++/CLI's version of C# using blocks, but much much nicer.  Anyway, `marshal_context` isn't needed when you are using `PtrToStringChars`.

Comment: Your final version is using strings after their memory has been freed. I really suggest the technique shown in my answer, but if you do use `marshal_as` with a `marshal_context`, make sure the `marshal_context` lives long enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are better ways for getting a C-style string from a `System::String^`.  Have a look at the `marshal_as` and `marshal_context` templates supplied with VC++.

Your immediate problem here is that you are compiling for Unicode, so `LoadLibrary` requires a unicode string, but `StringToHGlobalAnsi` does not return a unicode string.  No amount of pointer casting will change the encoding of the string pointed to.

You also have a memory leak.

Try this instead:

```
#include <vcclr.h>

// System::String always stored as Unicode, get a Unicode pointer with no conversion necessary
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(string);
// Always use the Unicode version of LoadLibrary
HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);
```

If this works and the above doesn't, then something is wrong with the string sent from C#:

```
System::String^ string = gcnew System::String(L"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\Server\\jvm.dll");
pin_ptr<const WCHAR> lib_name = PtrToStringChars(string);
HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryW(lib_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help tried your method and it sill has the same issues. I also tried with the methods in the updated post.  Very weird IMO.

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot: Which of the issues do you still have?  Is it a compile error (show the message) or a runtime error?  What is the value of `string`?

Comment: BTW, the `_T` makes either an ANSI string or a Unicode string, depending on your compile settings.  Since you are compiling for Unicode, `L"jvm.dll"` would give you the same effect.  You don't actually have any double backslashes in the string, right, only in the code that makes the string?

Comment: Runtime error... the LoadLibrary() returns NULL.  But the code runs & compiles w/o problems.  Wehn I substitute the #define RUNTIME_DLL it runs fine... and actually loads the jvm.dll file and the program works perfectly.  And yes, I don't have any double backslashes - verified that it shows as c:\program files\...\jvm.dll in the variables during debug.

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot: Try this version (it was messed up momentarily, should be ok now).

Comment: Added the "\0" to end of strings in both C# and C++ code and LoadLibrary() still returned NULL. When  I add your code right after my code fails - (ur 2nd code block) using gcnew string it works perfectly and loads the library. Not sure what could be wrong with the C# strings. I added the "\0" to the end of those too but no success.